# How should I transform this time series such that the magnitude of each value can be compared without the effect of the decreasing variance?

Tags: time-series, variance, stationarity, heteroscedasticity

this is my first post and it's nice to join this community. I'm not exactly an expert at statistics, but I really enjoy it. The following problem has become somewhat of an enigma for me.

I have this time series, which I first detrended using nonparametric regression of a moving median. I decided to use the moving median as an intermediate step as I wanted to the model to be as robust as possible and I want it to best reflect the central tendency of the data (do you approve of this approach?). I am now looking for a way to scale these values so that magnitudes can be compared without the effect of the decreasing volatility over time. I suppose this is a case of having to remove heteroskedasticity, and I'm uncertain of the best way to go about this.

I've already tried this:

1. I've tried a type of median absolute deviation with a moving window, and then divided each value in the detrended series by it. This seems to blow areas of low volatility out of proportion, regardless of the window used.
2. I took a moving median across several seasonal cycles, for instance, you take the median of n past values of Monday, then Tuesday, and so on. I then took a moving standard deviation of this new series and used it to divide each of the detrended values. Again, the results weren't stellar, with non-uniform variance across the series and values further to the right getting blown out of proportion.

In my research I've come across a few possible tools. The Box-Cox power transform is frequently mentioned. I've also read a lot about GARCH models, but how I would use it to achieve my goal isn't very clear to me. Again, I want to transform this series in such a way that, apart from outliers, volatility is more or less constant throughout, and the magnitude of values can be compared independent of the level of volatility prevailing at the time. In other words, I want to know how large a certain deviation is, given the current expected deviation. What would your approach to this problem be?

Any help is much appreciated.

[image: time series]